# MvxImageViewLoader behaviour overriding (Caching, Images appearing etc.)

Tags: image, caching, xamarin, mvvmcross

I use **MvxImageViewLoader** for **MvvmCross Xamarin** applications.

This component is really great and simplifies the images loading pretty much, but it (at least, out-of-the-box) is *pretty basic* and most of modern applications *require some reacher functionality*, for instance, **loading/progress images** or images nice **appearing/transitions** (possibly with **custom animation**).

I see there is **DefaultImagePath** property, but that's static image, which I can probably use by default, but that's ***not animated view or something***.

So, is there **any way to customize/extend** the loader **behaviour** (for *default image appearing*, *images transition* (from default to loaded)) etc?

---

And also I've noticed that the loader **caches** the image and even if I *trigger bound property changing* (leaving the image url the same) **it does not refresh** the image. I guess, "caching" really means caching and so on, but what if I need to change the user icon or something... **how can I forse the cache refreshing** with the image loader?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> So, is there any way to customize/extend the loader behaviour (for default image appearing, images transition (from default to loaded)) etc?

No - advanced features like fade-in/fade-out/animated-placeholder display aren't supported within the standard MvvmCross image view, and no-one that I know of has provided any samples or tutorials about how this can be done.

For adding such functionality, you can use normal software techniques - inheritance, aggregation and cut, copy, paste. e.g. you could simply create your own `AgatImageView`  which had the behaviour your app requires based on [MvxImageView.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxImageView.cs).

Some examples of creating your own data-bound controls is given in N=18 and N-19 of http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com/

Comment: Well, I totally understand the approach MvvmCross uses here and the fact, that that might be tricky to "fit" any developer's taste in fading outs etc. (especially, considering mutli-platforming). But that would be much easier to implement any such "fancy" things if there is just some event like "OnImageLoadingComplete". Is there any chance just to expand the functionality via inheriting the base class, or the only way to manage that is to extend sources and recompile code (or even request PullRequest)?

Comment: I'd encourage you to take some time to experiment and prototype. You'll find that an `ImageChanged` event is already exposed and I'd suspect that you could use that event for your current requirements. Yes MvvmCross accepts some PullRequests, but we also encourage people to build alternate plugins and to build extension libraries. As you say, one library cannot fit every developer's tastes and needs. Further, building extensions also gives contributors more room to learn, experiment and build. Over and out on this one. Stuart

Comment: Actually, after some explorations I've bumped into "afterImageChangeAction" param of MvxImageViewLoader constructor. This is mostly all what I needed as for the image loading completion.

Comment: However, the question with caching is still not really clear for me. I've spent a few hours exploring all the plugins/managers/configurations classes and even added some property (with the sources recompiling) to have something like ((MvxImageCache<UIImage>) Mvx.Resolve<IMvxImageCache<UIImage>>()).MaxInMemoryFiles = 0; But I still can not get rid of caching somewhy. (The caching makes problems especially on debugging/developing stage). There are some configuration classes, but I can not find how I can use them easily.

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned in upper comments you may use default iOS' `UIActivityIndicatorView` for showing progress and you should hide the progress in afterImageChangeAction, you can check if `UIImageView.Image` field is not null, to make sure that the image is loaded.

Regarding the caching, it's not that easy here. By default `MvxImageViewLoader` relies on MvvmCross framework's implementation of `IMvxFileDownloadCache` interface. This interface has only one public method `RequestLocalFilePath()`, so even if you get an instance from IoC container (`Mvx.Resolve()`) you won't be able to clean-up the existing cache (to do that you need to reset `private _entriesByHttpUrl` field of `MvxFileDownloadCache` class).

If you really need this, you have to copy-paste existing MvxFileDownloadCache class and make your tweaks. But I am not sure about your use-cases where you need this. If you download images from the web, the URL of the image is a sort of a key in the cache, so if you need to reload just change the URL.

Maybe you could use some old-school approach like adding GET parameters to the URL: http://mydomain.com/images/myimage.jpg?timestamp=123456. Usually this helps everywhere :-). Although I didn't test it with `MvxImageViewLoader`, it's just my best guess.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, the stuff with afterImageChangeAction is already mentioned in bottom comments. So, this is the way how I already do that.

But as for the caching, the strange thing is that MvvmCross positioned as very flexible for customization and when exploring its sources, I've found that there are even some special class(es) for the cache (and other plugins) settings initialization, but all those are internal and there is no simple way to use such behaviour outside of the framework. (At least, I did not find and not details about that in docs (If there are docs any)).

Comment: As for the url params: of course, this is the way I manage that, but that just complicates the logic. There is also no ability to extend the functionality (of the plugin) (for instance, to detect http header 'Last-modified').